# SvelteKit loading indicator when a page load time threshold is exceeded

Tags: sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit for a website that is mainly server-side rendered pages. The client-side navigation on SvelteKit works beautifully and is super snappy. However, sometimes, when the backend server is called in the route `load()` function, the response is not instant and maybe several seconds because of the database long-tail latency.

What would be the best way to create a loading indicator that is only displayed if the loading time is not instant (sub 200ms)? I am aware of the generic [navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68325048/315168) pattern, but I specifically hope to create a loading indicator that is not triggered unless the page load is not instant.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75052635/338897 the `+loading.svelte` is coming

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sveltekit has a store variable called "navigating" which literally indicates if the client is in-between loading pages. From the [Sveltekit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores):

> `navigating` is a readable store. When navigating starts, its value is `{ from, to }`, where `from` and `to` both mirror the page store value. When
> `navigating` finishes, its value reverts to `null`.

Note, that if your page is pre-rendered, it should be "instant" and thus not show a loading indicator. If not, this "navigating" variable will be not null for as long as it takes for your content to be fetched and/or rendered. If you wanted to, you could make the "Spinner" component show nothing...until after 200ms (using a [setTimout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) timer)...which it sounds like you do want.

Here's a sample implementation from a wrapper component I have used in the past (pardon the tailwindcss syntax...I copied and pasted it). You can customize this idea in `__layout.svelte` or wrap components or entire "pages" with this `{#if $navigating}` logic:

```html
<script>
// USE THIS:
import { navigating } from '$app/stores'
// Example spinner/loading component is visible (when $navigating != null):
import Spinner from '$lib/design/Spinner.svelte'
...
</script>

  <main class="py-4">
    <div class="pagePaddingMain flex-col">
      {#if title}
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-center text-cText pb-4 sm:text-5xl">{title}</h1>
      {/if}
      {#if $navigating} <!-- LOOK HERE -->
        <div class="m-8">
          <Spinner />
          <h1 class="ext-3xl text-center text-cText">Fetching {title}...</h1>
        </div>
      {:else}
        <slot />
      {/if}
    </div>
  </main>
```

That's it. Good luck!

Comment: This does not work if you are using svelte ( and not sveltekit). I am getting the following error:
**Could not find module in path: '$app/stores' relative to '/App.svelte'** 
Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-framework-32h4w2?file=/App.svelte

Comment: @manojadams because svelte doesn't has $app/store. its a builtin functionality of sveltekit.

Comment: @HNazmulHassan ok. I did guessed that. But can you tell me how to use a functionality like `navigating` in svelte. It ideally should be part of svelte itself.